# Tor & dns cached

Tags: anonymity

On linux with wireshark I saw a lot of dns activity including a request for a site I am pretty sure I visited with Tor browser bundle earlier a few days ago.
Not visited with regular firefox. However dns request made without Tor browser bundle running. Coincidence ? My mistake seeing things not there ?

After looking into the strange (lot of) dns activity it seemed to me it was caused by nscd. After removing nscd from the system, traffic went relatively quit as far as dns. 
Also I set both

**network.dnsCacheExpiration** and 
**network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod**

to zero to kill any cache dns activity.

Could it be that nscd can leak what sites are visited with Tor browser bundle?
Maybe illogical, but just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Could have been a prefetch (dns or otherwise) (with no actual human intended visit) from the standard firefox for a link on stackexchange or other site with lot of links, coincidentally the same as visited earlier with TorBrowserBundle. So no definite alarm.
But if someone with more knowledge has a better (worst case) explanation...